# Mongoose version Key and _id set to false not working npm version 5.12.9

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hello guys I am using Mongoose for interacting with MongoDB, Actually I want to turn off `_id` and `_v` for not coming for my each document but as you can see I do set those options to `false` but when I run my code and get data from the database using `.find()` method I can see those fields are still coming. Can anyone tell me how can I fix this ? Thanks in Advance.

```
const clanData = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    isWarLogPublic: {
      type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.Boolean,
    },
    tag: {
      type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.String,
    },
    locationID: {
      type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.Number,
    },
  },
  {
    versionKey: false,
  },
  { _id: false }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("ClanData", clanData);
```

Comment: it should be in second parameter, `{ versionKey: false, _id: false }` see [mongoose schema guide](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html)

Comment: @turivishal still not working, I am still getting both of them 
```
 {
    _id: 60a17401b8ed401710c5c02b,
    isWarLogPublic: false,
    tag: '#P8LPJPVV',
    locationID: 32000006,
    __v: 0
  },
```

Comment: probably you are missing something, check other possibilities, is this old entry or did you tried adding new document? edit your question add mongoose npm version in your question and also last tried that i have suggested in first comment...

Comment: @turivishal No I did not added anything for now, I added this data's yesterday now I am trying to get this from the DB now.

Comment: it will not change existing data, it will work when you add new data..

Comment: if you want to exclude from find() result, use projection `.find({}, { _id: 0, versionKey: 0 })`

Comment: @turivishal well I removed the data added those again when I now try to get the data back from the DB I get only the ObjectId and other data's and that _v thankfully not coming but I want to turn off that _id too not sure why its not working. This is how I am doing as per you said 
`

`{
    versionKey: false,
    _id: false
  },
`

Comment: confirm from both what is your expectation, 1) you don't want to insert both fields in database 2) both will be insert in database but you just want to exclude from result only?

Comment: @turivishal I only want the Object Id to get showed in the DB but when I should get it I dont want that. I only want my 3 field

Comment: no problem, you can answer your solution and accept it if you want..

Comment: @turivishal sorry for disturbing you again since I am only excluding the data without the IDs actually can I now get the ID without actually showing it while getting all those data from the database ?

Comment: not getting you exactly..

Comment: @turivishal Well what I need is currently I don't have the IDs for my each document. Well I am just excluding it I can include it too. But what will happen is I am doing an comparison check with those data on the DB with the same data I am getting from the API. Basically the data I am getting is all from an API source so since API don't have anytype of special ID source the comparison checker will check for those ID too. Which I don't want.